# Isn't every increasing continuous convex function strictly increasing (disregarding $f(x) \equiv 0$)?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Isn't every increasing continuous convex function $f$ strictly increasing (disregarding the trivial case $f(x) \equiv 0$)?

I don't see any counterexample!

Comment: How about $f(x)\equiv 4$?

Comment: $f(x) = x + \lvert x\rvert$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not exactly.
Remember that increasing in general means that if $a_1=<a_2=<...$ then $f(a_1)=<f(a_2)=<...$
this means that the function may still be convex, but that the global minimum/maximum is not unique. If it were strictly convex, you may easily visualize why the global minimum/maximum would be unique in that case.

A counter-example could be any function whose global minimum is not unique, some of which are mentioned in the comments above